# PHP - Download file and print something after

Tags: php

I have a problem, i want my php code to download a file so i use the function Header().

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $licensename . '.lic"');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($license));
header('Connection: close');
```

And this is working but i want my code to print something else just after that ( or just before, this is not a problem )

```
<?php

echo $json;

?>
```

If i do this, the json will be printed in the downloaded file and that's not what i want.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Once your PHP output is directed towards a download you cannot change it, all the output of the PHP script will be downloaded. You could use Javascript, in the page that called your PHP script, to echo something else, perhaps in combination with another PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

Since the HTTP headers cannot be changed after the server responds the response cannot be both a plain text file and an HTML page. If you want a message to appear after the file download process is initiated I suggest that you allow the download process to happen asynchronously using a JavaScript XHR request (Ajax) and then show a message using JavaScript once the asynchronous function has been executed. If you must redirect the user, redirect them to an HTML page and then use JavaScript to initiate the download process over there.